# conditionally implement an interface

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to do some animations in my app and had a way to do it without using `ObjectAnimator` and `AnimatorListener` from `API 11`. However, they're not as smooth and robust as just doing animations using those classes.

So I made the changes to my code in my object's class with a check for the API level, so that `ObjectAnimator` and `AnimatorListener` stuff wouldn't be called unless the API level is 11+.

The problem is that my object is implementing `AnimatorListener` even though its functionality isn't being used in all versions of the code. I think this is leading to an `VerifyError` on start up of my app because now it crashes on devices with API level 10 and down.

Is there a way to conditionally implement an interface based on the API level or a different way to achieve the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, it is OK if you build against or with a higher SDK target, the issue is only when your code is really run on a device missing classes from a higher SDK. As others suggested, you can go for a factory

```
public class Factory {
  public static <T> T getImplementation(){
    if(<SDK_LEVEL_INCOMPATIBLE>){
      return (T)new <package>.OldSchoolAnimator();
    }else{
      return (T)new <package>.SuperAnimator();
    }
  }
}


...
SomeImplementation impl = new Factory().getImplementation();
...
```

watchout, "SomeImplementation" has to be a common super-type or interface of OldSchoolAnimator and SuperAnimator classes! Dont use "imports" for implementation classes in your factory, rather use full-qualified classnames.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/ which backports the animation UI to pre-11.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the factory design pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Perhaps provide a relevant example rather than just a link. Withholding +1 until I see more effort :D

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an anonymous inner class for the listener and used the full-qualified classnames instead of importing the other animation objects!